# Is there an analytical solution for this system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am struggling with the system of differential equations

$$\begin{array}{rl} \frac{dy}{dt} &= av(t) - by\\ \frac{dz}{dt} &= c k(t) y(t) - dz\end{array}$$

for which I am seeking an analytical solution. If I understood it right, the solution for the first one should look like this

$$y(t)=\left(\int av(t)e^{bt}dt+C\right)e^{-bt}$$

but I am a little confused on how to tackle the second one. Thank you, and hope you have a nice day.

Comment: In the second equation you just need to replace $y(t)$ by the solution that you have found for the first equation and then proceed in the same manner.